# Add haproxy X-Forwarded-Host request header

Tags: haproxy, http-headers, x-forwarded-for

I have a Haproxy instance that rewrites `Host` headers to internal ones using `http-request set-header`.

```
http-request set-header Host internal.example
```

However, I'd still like backends to have access to the original `Host` header. I think `X-Forwarded-Host` is a good candidate for this, however I'm struggling to figure out how to do that.

I'm using this, which works:

```
capture request header Host len 64
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Host %hrl
```

But of course that's a giant hack - won't work for more than 64 chars and won't work if I ever need to capture another header.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why are you changing these headers?

Answer (score 7):

As Joel E Salas has mentioned via a comment, changing the `Host` header is a slight strange thing to do, but I suppose if the backends only understand certain values it could make sense.

In any event, you can just use the `req.hdr` fetch sample as a variable to `http-request`, thusly:

```
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Host %[req.hdr(Host)]
```

You'll have to run that before you run the `http-request set-header` that rewrites the `Host` header, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks! Setting this variable allows us to do further processing on an IIS back-end site based on the value of the original host header (another domain or subdomain that was an alias for a back-end server). It comes through to IIS as HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST, which can be used as a conditional match pattern in the IIS rewrite rule. We had been using just HTTP_HOST in the rewrite rule prior to fronting it with haproxy.